# nginx server everything under / except for one uri

Tags: nginx, location

I am having three URLs I want to be able to call:

- example.com/
- example.com/gdpr
- example.com/api

example.com/api is actually a reverse proxy, all other locations are pointing to my document root where there are static html files.

My server config looks like this:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    index index.html;

    root /var/www/html; 

    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
    }   

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I could create a new location called /gdpr/ and it will work. Unfortunately this is not very comfortable if the site increases.

The behavior right now is:

- example.com/ => 200
- example.com/gdpr => 404
- example.com/api => 200

Can you please let me know, how I can handle this in a way, that /api/ is a reverse proxy, but everything else acts normally under the root?

Answer (score 1):

I made it work by adding

```
try_files $uri /index.html;
```

in the location / section